# Problem with Component Resource Injection using Swing Application Framework

Tags: java, swing, saf

I'm having a problem using the [Swing Application Framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/)'s Component Resource Injection, I read the tutorial provided by Sun and it kinda works.

The case is that I have a class `Program` that extends from the [`SingleFrameApplication`](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication.html) provided by de SAF, now I want to get the text of my components (buttons and labels, etc.) from a properties file and it works as expected for that `Program` class, (I created a subdirectory called `resources` and put the `Program.properties` file in there). But, I have a `MainFrame` within a subpackage named `mainpkg.gui` (the `Program` is within the `mainpkg` package) and I created the corresponding `resources` subsubpackage for placing the `MainFrame.properties` file, and it does not work! I cannot get the bundle (automatically, I guess if I use the `ResourceMap.getXXX()` method I'd get the stuff.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your MainFrame a subclass of `SingleFrameApplication` ? or is it a direct descendant of `JFrame` ?

Comment: Is your MainFrame realized dynamically?  You can inject the resources dynamically Application.getInstance().getContext().getResourceMap().injectComponent(this);

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here's what I think is the problem:

First, if you use `SingleFrameApplication`, you shouldn't create your own `JFrame`. Instead, you should have a `startup()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void startup() {
    final FrameView view = getMainView();
    view.setMenuBar(createMenuBar());
    view.setComponent(createMainComponent());
    show(view);
}
```

Now, the `show(view)` method takes care of injecting all those resources into the components. But it processes only the components that are in the component hierarchy of the `view` at the moment you call `show()`. If you add something later, you will have to inject the resources yourself. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
public void injectResources(final Component root) {
    final ResourceMap resourceMap = applicationContext.getResourceMap(root
            .getClass(), Object.class);
    resourceMap.injectComponents(root);
    resourceMap.injectFields(root);
}
```

I hope this helps you or someone else with the same problem.